# Queue Calls to Method

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, task-parallel-library

I have a C# Method (SendAndGet) it sends a message to the Serial Port and waits for a response or times out. I am using System.IO.SerialPort to communicate with the Serial Port.

I have several areas in my application that call the SendAndGet method. I have a timer that makes a call every 100ms and events that happen will also then make calls to this Method. I am looking for a way to Queue these calls so that I can allow the method to complete before the next call is allowed? Not sure how to do this. Did a lot of Googling and bing searches before posting. I don't think the TPL will works for me?

Comment: Are all your timers and events happening on the GUI thread?  If so, then in a sense they're already "queued"--only one can run at a time.  That is, unless your `SendAndGet` method is starting threads (or using them from a thread pool, etc.).

Comment: Does the message you receive from the serial port matter? If you're only worried about sending, that's one thing (use a lock) but if you need a response back (timed out, etc) that's a bit more complicated.
Related, does the response have to be associated with the request?

Comment: @adv12 sorry just one timer (I edited my question) and it happens on the GUI thread. Bases on the data received from the Serial Port and other commands that the end user might send(by pushing a button on GUI) use the SendAndGet method. The SendAndGet method just uses the Write and ReadTo of the SerialPort.

Comment: @lucrativelucas yes, the data received from the serial port is important.

Answer (score 1):

The TPL in fact makes this quite a lot easier to work with than earlier options.

What we'll do is create a class that wraps a `SerialPort`, exposing a asynchronous method to send a request and get a response, queuing the requests through a single port.

This class will also have a private `Task` that represents the last request sent out; when a new request comes in it'll add a continuation to that task to start doing its real work, and then assign itself as the new "last task".

For the actual implementation of your `SendAndGet` method we'll `await` the last task, so that we don't start until the last task finishes, we can then send the data through the port, wait for the data to be received (asynchronously) and process the results.  Note that in your case you'll presumably want to change the return type of the method from `Task` to `Task<T>` where `T` is the actual data that you have parsed out of the serial port.

```
public class AsyncSerialPort
{
    private SerialPort port;
    private Task lastRequest = Task.FromResult(true);
    public AsyncSerialPort()
    {
        //initialize port here
    }

    public Task SendAndGet()
    {
        lock (lastRequest)
        {
            var result = SendAndGetImpl();
            lastRequest = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
    private async Task SendAndGetImpl()
    {
        await lastRequest;
        //send data to port
        var type = await port.WhenDataRecieved();
        //process the received data

    }
}
```

The other thing that we'll need is an implementation for `WhenDataRecieved`; some way of getting a `Task` that represents when data is received, so that we can `await` it.

```
public static Task<SerialData> WhenDataRecieved(this SerialPort port)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SerialData>();
    SerialDataReceivedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, args) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(args.EventType);
        port.DataReceived -= handler;
    };
    port.DataReceived += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: thank you trying to add this class to my code. Having a issue with 'var type = await port.WhenDataRecieved();'  compiler says WhenDataRecieved() not part of System.IO.SerialPort. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @stopmotion24 The definition of the method is right in this answer.

Comment: I apologize I think I must me missing a step to get this part to work 'await port.WhenDataRecieved();' I assume this might be some sort of class that wraps the System.IO.SerialPort?

Comment: @stopmotion24 It's exactly the method that I provided in my answer, and nothing else.  It's an extension method.